# Test hangs on checking dialog fragment with Espresso

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso

I'm writing a test for an activity that shows a confirmation dialog once a network request is made and received. I'm using `onView(withText(confirmText)).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` to check for the dialog, and I've also removed the `inRoot()` call, but whatever I do, the test just hangs here and never completes.

I have also included an IdlingResource for this activity that is set to idle when I receive a successful network call, yet whether or not that is registered seems to make little difference. It seems the problem here is mainly in checking the dialog. Here is the test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

public class RequestActivityTest {

```
private DialogFragmentIdlingResource mDialogFragmentIdlingResource;
private String mTestRequest;
private String mTopic;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<RequestActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(RequestActivity.class);

@Before
public void setUp() {
    registerIdlingResource();
    mTestRequest = "Test request";
    mTopic = "Appliance";
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    unregisterIdlingResource();
}

@Test
public void enterText() {
    onView(withId(R.id.request_input)).perform(typeText(mTestRequest));
}

@Test
public void checkMessageSent() {

    mActivityTestRule.getActivity().setTopic(mTopic);
    onView(withId(R.id.request_input)).perform(typeText(mTestRequest));
    onView(withId(R.id.submit_request_button)).perform(click());
    String confirmText = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getString(R.string.confirm_request_dialog_message);
    onView(withText(confirmText)).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}

public void registerIdlingResource() {
    mDialogFragmentIdlingResource = (DialogFragmentIdlingResource) mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mDialogFragmentIdlingResource);
}

public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
    if (mDialogFragmentIdlingResource != null) {
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mDialogFragmentIdlingResource);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Activity methods for sending the network request and registering idling resource:

```
private void sendMessage() {
    if (UserPreferences.getUserProfile().getCompanyProfile() != null) {
        if (NetworkUtils.isConnectedToInternet(this)) {
            if (mNetworkErrorMessageSnackbar != null) mNetworkErrorMessageSnackbar.dismiss();
            String message = mRequestMessage.getText().toString();
            mRequestPresenter.onRequestSubmit(UserPreferences.getUserProfile().getCompanyProfile()
                    .getBuilding().getId(), mTopic, message);
            setFragmentIdle();
        } else {
            mNetworkErrorMessageSnackbar = new NetworkErrorMessageSnackbar
                    .Builder(HttpStatusCode.NO_INTERNET, mRequestLayout, this).build();
            mNetworkErrorMessageSnackbar.show();
        }
    }
}

@VisibleForTesting
    @NonNull
    public IdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
        if (mDialogFragmentIdlingResource == null) {
            mDialogFragmentIdlingResource = new DialogFragmentIdlingResource(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), ConfirmationDialogFragment.TAG);
        }
        return mDialogFragmentIdlingResource;
    }

    public  void setFragmentIdle() {
        if (mDialogFragmentIdlingResource != null) {
            mDialogFragmentIdlingResource.isIdleNow();
        }
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        mTopic = topic;
    }
```

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this?  I am facing a similar use case.